# How to implement accessibility on a native winform custom listview control when list items are drawn

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, accessibility, custom-controls

We have windows form with custom Listview control and all the Rows and subitems are rendered by using draw() method. Now we want to make our application accessibility compliant and the Screen readers like Narrator/NVDA tools doesn't read the Listview items. Tool just reading "Selected Item" where as it should read out "Selected Item 0 Column text" should be read upon selecting row.

We have tried setting "Name" property to column value and also tried setting "AccessibleName" property, which didn't work.
We where drawing first column an icon, have tried removing icon column but no luck.

After adding properties using reflection, property values where shown empty string when observed UI with "Inspect.exe" tool.

```
public class QueueListItem : ListViewItem
    {
        public QueueListItem(){
        Type type = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("AccessibleName");
        property.SetValue(this, "Test QueueListView Item", null);
    }

}
```

Can someone help us guiding best way to do this? Screen reader tool should read at least first column value upon selection.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE] that demonstrates your implementation of the ListView, how you add a ListViewItem to its Rows collection and most importantly what your Draw method does. Because based on its name I suspect you basically do that: ownerdraw the controls in which case there is not much left for accessibility to act on.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395817/accessibleobject-implementation-for-custom-controls

Comment: Thanks @rene, Overridable method "CreateAccessibilityInstance" is missing in ListViewItem & ListView Class to implement. We are not using any bind method to add rows, based on certain events we get the data to be added to List and we are calling following code                                                   
TextRenderer.DrawText(de.Graphics, strAttrValue, GetFont(de.Font), rect, new Pen(de.Brush).Color, TextFormat);

Comment: I didn't dig very deep but ListViewItem doesn't derrive from Control which basically puts you out of any out-of-the-box support for that AccessibleObject. You have to redesign your form by using only classes that inherit from Control. If that is not an option, you have to roll your own implementation of [AccessibleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.accessibleobject?view=netframework-4.8) for your own class but that needs lots of handling, specially COM marshalling and that is way too broad to capture in a single answer I'm afraid.

Comment: @rene thanks a lot for the valuable suggestions. Even am scared to make those changes. Only way that i could see is implementing AccessibleObject, but afraid about handing COM which might add up some memory leaks.